# MySQL select fields from row where criteria met, and field from row above

Tags: mysql, database

I have a data table of results where I would like to select information which is mostly held against the record relating to the second-place finisher.

So, for example, the location of the race, the date of the race, and the time deficit to the winner.

But what I would like to show in my query is the winner followed by their winning margin, which is actually stored against the record relating to the second-place finisher.

For example:

```
id | race_id | result | Entrant       | Time
---|---------|--------|---------------|------
0  |   001   |    1   | Huw Edwards   | 54:78.491
1  |   001   |    2   | Fiona Bruce   | 0.250
2  |   001   |    3   | Sophie Raworth| 3.114
3  |   001   |    4   | George Alagiah| 6.756
4  |   001   |    5   | Mishal Husain | 42.452
5  |   001   |    6   | Peter Sissons | 58.004
6  |   002   |    1   | Fiona Bruce   | 43:08.549
7  |   002   |    2   | Sophie Raworth| 5.439
8  |   002   |    3   | Mishal Husain | 5.444
9  |   002   |    4   | Huw Edwards   | 6.007
10 |   002   |    5   | Peter Sissons | 13.000
11 |   002   |    6   | George Alagiah| 2:12.782
```

I have tried a query such as this (not working as desired):

```
SELECT r.id, r.entrant, r.time 
FROM races as r 
LEFT JOIN races as r1 
ON r1.id > r.id 
WHERE r.result = "2"
```

I'd like to end up with a result like the following, because it shows the winning margin that Huw Edwards enjoyed.

```
id | race_id | entrant     | time
---|---------|-------------|-------
 1 |  001    | Huw Edwards | 0.250
 7 |  002    | Fiona Bruce | 5.439
```

Here is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `races` (
 `series` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `year` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `round` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `race_id` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `track` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `result` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `number` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `class` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `class_pos` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `runner` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `runner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `runner2` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `runner_id2` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `entrant` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `laps` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `time` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `best` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `qual` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `marque` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=43021 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: This isn't really enough information to help you. Where is the race ID stored? That's a necessary part of your query.

Comment: What's your logic in your question? it is not clear.

Comment: The race ID is stored in the table 'races' if you hadn't worked it out...

Comment: How would your table structure support multiple races?

Comment: There is a race ID field as well which isn't included in this example for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not 100% clear what do you want to get.

Please provide more examples with some other expected results.
So far, to give you some ideas of how you can get data you need:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7eb44f/2

```
SELECT r.id,
      r.race_id,
       r.entrant,
       r1.entrant as Winner, 
       r1.time WinnerTime,
       r.time 
FROM races as r 
LEFT JOIN races as r1 
ON r1.result = 1 
   AND r1.race_id = r.race_id
WHERE r.result = 2
```

**UPDATE** Your table schema is terrible. to make my query faster for your table you should at least change `race_id` column type integer (or varchar) but not text! And you need then to create an index over `result` and `race_id` columns:

```
ALTER TABLE races MODIFY race_id INTEGER; 

CREATE INDEX result_race_id ON races (result, race_id);
```

Comment: I've edited my question now and realise I should have included the unique identifier for each race. Hopefully the addition of the second intended result row from the select statement helps. I've tried some of the responses in this thread, but it seems like they take longer than expected to process.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I've now run this on a data table of ~42,000 rows in phpmyadmin, but the query takes around 55 seconds. Is it expected to run slow on a dataset of 42k?

Comment: Provide your table schema: `SHOW CREATE TABLE races;`?

Comment: OMG! `'time' varchar(256)` **WHY?**

Comment: It sometimes contains comments.

Comment: Thank you very much - huge improvements and I know where to do my homework  now. Appreciate the critical comments.

Comment: Don't forget to approve my answer ;-) Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated query:

```
select id, entrant, (
    select time
    from races x
    where race_id = races.race_id AND result = 2
) as win_margin
from races
where result = 1
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the x after races? Is it just an alias? It seems to work fine without it.

Comment: Yes it is an alias. It'll be useful if you want to reference the outer table (e.g. `x.raceid = races.raceid`)

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks pretty close, you just want to use the correct aliases - so you want r1.time and r1.result instead or r.time and r.result

```
SELECT r.id, r.entrant, r1.time 
FROM races as r 
LEFT JOIN races as r1 
ON r1.id > r.id 
WHERE r1.result = "2"
```